# In what basis the cost for impression per 1000 views calculated? day / month

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I own a small website with few visits per day.

I am using 7 ads at maximum in a page.

I get average views per day : 30

In what basis the cost for impression per 1000 views calculated? day / month

At the end of day or month?

Or when I got 1000 impressions?

Comment: 7 ads is WAY too much.   Your page is going to look very poor quality and spammy to users.   It is better to limit the ads to 3.   I've found that two ads well placed above the fold performs better than more ads sprinkled throughout my pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPM is just the outcome of (Estimated earnings / Number of page views) * 1000. CPM is calculated with the values of earnings and number of page views, it doesn't determine what you will be paid for future impressions.

Certain ads pay more than others so for example if you only have 1 ad impression and the viewer legitimately clicked on the ad and you were credited $2 for that single ad impression/click your CPM would show as $2000 but of course you wouldn't expect to actually make $2000 per 1000 views.

Comment: My question is when i reach 1000 impression(it will took many days), will google adsense pay me?

Comment: Google will pay you once you reach the payment threshold, I'm pretty sure this amount is $100USD.

Comment: At 30 views per day it will take years to reach the $100 payment threshold.  Assuming a typical $2 RPM you will make about $2 per month.  It will take you 4 years to make $100 from your website.    There is also the wrinkle of estimated vs finalized earnings.  Not all your estimated earnings will get paid.   Google doesn't pay you if the advertiser doesn't pay them.  Google doesn't pay if they think a click could be a mistake or fraud.  You don't know that until the end of the month, and even afterwards, they may deduct from the next month's earnings.